# "it doesn't - right?" sentence meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, paragraphs

[from podcast transcript](https://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=632612110)

> WOOD: So one, when he has 45 minutes to get up on stage, I want people to pay close attention to the logical flow of his argument, to the evidence he's providing, to the lack there of, **right?**  I want people to see what kinds of questions make him backpedal, what
>   kind of questions make a pause, **right?** Where is he - because this is
>   in the public sphere, in the political sphere. When you're getting
>   things done, it's always going to be contentious, whether the issue's
>   welfare, whether it's crime, whether it's taxation, **it doesn't -
>   right?**

I have two questions:

1. What is the meaning of the bold sentence from the paragraph above, what's the point of adding "right?" ?
2. And what does "it doesn't" refers to?

Thanks for answering!!

Comment: That "right" is just an ill-mannered attempt to compensate for the lack of faith - either in one's own powers of persuasion, or in the audience's ability to keep up and agree with even the most obvious (in the speaker's opinion). The "it doesn't" part is probably an abbreviated version of "it doesn't matter."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to understand podcast transcriptions isn't a particularly easy task. When people are speaking spontaneously (rather than reading a prepared script), they often leave sentences unfinished, or revise what they're saying partway through a sentence. "It doesn't - right?" is not a complete sentence.

Ricky's suggestion that Wood was planning to say "it doesn't matter" makes sense to me. "It doesn't matter whether the issue's welfare, crime, or taxation—when you're getting things done, it's always going to be contentious."

Comment: Thanks for answering! But, what doesn't matter? being contentious? I don't understand what "it doesn't matter"  is referring to.

Comment: @CYU We don't know what it refers to, it's just a badly written rant. A shame because he started out making some sort of sense.